# Python encoded string is still in binary format

Tags: python-3.x, character-encoding, beautifulsoup, urllib3

I am trying some website scraping using urllib3 and beautiful soup. Python 3 encoding/decoding is tripping me up. This is my code

```
r = http.request('GET', 'https://www.************************.jsf')

if(r.status == 200):
    page = r.data.decode('utf-8')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)  

    print(soup.prettify())
    #This prints - [Decode error - output not utf-8]
    #              [Decode error - output not utf-8]

    print(soup.prettify().encode('utf-8'))
    #This prints the data but with binary mark
    # b'<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//D.......
    #..........................................'
```

As I had done the decoding `r.data.decode('utf-8')` before calling beautiful soup, why do I need to encode it again and why does it still show b'' marking even after converting it to string

Comment: The `data` attribute isn't documented. Why is there also no `getresponse()` call?

Comment: I was reading through urllib3 documentation over at readthedocs. could not find any reference to getresponse(). Also, the data attribute is pretty much the only way to access the response content there ..`https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html`. Maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

The `b'xxx'` is the representation of the binary type value (sequence of bytes -- which is natural result of the `.encode()`. The `print()` function automatically converts the object to its representation if it is not a string.

Try to write the debug infor into a file. The `print` function may have problems with output to a console that supports certain charset/encoding.